# How to use AWS SQS with AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-eks

we currently use AWS SQS with a worker instance and Elastic Beanstalk. As we are moving to Kubernetes with EKS we need a solution for using our SQS Queue.

Is there a simple solution like the worker instance for using a AWS Queue within a Kubernetes Cluster?

Comment: good question. it's (for me, really) hard to get workable example for what you describe. all I've managed to find is here: https://medium.com/easyread/consuming-sqs-message-using-golang-in-eks-elastic-kubernetes-service-from-aws-cf0b30ca0e01